# django-tables - Related field verbose name

Tags: django, django-models, localization, django-tables2

I'm using [`django-tables`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and trying to display a table containing some related fields.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=100)
    comp = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(_("country"), max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'comp', 'comp.country',)
        empty_text = _('No user')
```

I get the correct data but `Comp` in each related heading

```
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| Name | Comp           | Comp            |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| Bob  | Comp 1         | France          |
| John | Comp 2         | United Kingdom  |
| ...  | ...            | ...             |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
```

What could be the reason ?
Shouldn't I get `Name`, `Comp`, `Country` ?

---

**Update**

Mistake on the original question, I have updated it.

Comment: Just curious. Why `'user.pref.country', 'user.pref.phone'`? Why not just `'country', 'phone'`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I did a mistake on the question. It's updated

Answer (score 2):

Using `accessor` to resolve your fields allows to define the verbose names

```
class UserTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(accessor='name', verbose_name=_('name'))
    comp = tables.Column(accessor='comp', verbose_name=_('company'))
    country = tables.Column(accessor='comp.country', verbose_name=_('country'))
```

Comment: This worked for me when a custom column definition wasn't rendering the verbose name correctly even though it was in the same model (i.e. not a related field). Note that verbose name can be defined in models, too.

Answer (score 1):

From `django-table` docs -

> **fields** – specify model fields to include

But you're including relationships -

```
fields = ('user', 'user.pref.country', 'user.pref.phone',)
```

I never used that app, so I'm not sure how it's working, but I think it's taking the verbose name of each field, in later two cases, `user` field comes first, hence it's taking `user` fields' verbose name.

Update:

It seems you can provide custom verbose names, try this. Not sure if this will work, as Country is a related field. -

```
class UserTable(tables.Table):
    country = tables.Column(verbose_name="Country")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'comp', 'comp.country',)
        empty_text = _('No user')
```

Comment: Actually it works with relations because it fetches the correct data. But maybe it doesn't resolve verbose names for related fields indeed.

Comment: I saw that, but I wanted to take advantage of my already translated fields from models ie: `_("country")`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be happening. If it indeed is impossible with current logic, maybe you should look into the source code of `django-table` and see if you can extend or override the method that's creating the name.